# error message = library not found for -lbz2

Tags: delphi

I am trying to compile an app for iphone. I am using Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3, XCode 9.4.2, iOS 11.4.

I get the message even if i try to compile a blank project for ios.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Maidul

Comment: Xcode 9.4.2 has not even been released yet. Xcode 9.4.1 was released today. Are you using a beta? Using 9.4 (9F1027a), compiling a blank project works for me.

Comment: Also works with Xcode 9.4.1 (9F2000), which I've just installed. Compiles OK and IDE enters debug mode OK

Comment: Dear Mr. Dave, Thanks for your response. I am using xcode 9.4 (9F1027a). My Macos is running in VMware and version is High Sierra, 10.13.4. Can you please suggest me how do I setup the environment, so that It sync s to all? Thanks

Comment: I have macOS 10.13.5, Xcode 9.4.1 (9F2000), targeting iOS 11.4 SDK, Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3 with this patch installed: https://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/30835

Comment: Dear Mr. Dave, Thanks for your kind response. I have downloaded all the requirements as you have told me to do. But still I get the same error. I really do not have a clue now.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove any trial 3rd party component's library path will solve your issue, I had same issue and solved by removing trial 3rd party component's library path.